# d3 is not appending "rect" inside a <g>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

First time for me using d3 and trying to render a bar chart inside a React application. The code generates the elements , ,  and  (group) correctly, but do not generates 'rect' elements inside de  group element based on the data provided. ¿can you guys please point where the problem is?d3 is not appending "rect"  inside a

If I append manually a 'rect' inside de  , it works. But when I add the using  .data(data).enter(), no bar shows.

these are the elements that the code generates so far:

```
<div class="bargraph">
  <svg width="700" height="500">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="svgGradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
        <stop class="start" offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"> </stop>
        <stop class="end" offset="100%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

and here is the code:

```
import  React from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";

function Bargraph(data){

    let padding = 10;
    let barHeight = 46;
    let outerWidth = 700;
    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,153]);
        yScale.domain([0,d3.max(data, (d)=>parseFloat(d[1]))])

    var svg = d3.select('.bargraph').append('svg').attr('width', 700).attr('height', 500);

    var definitions = svg.append('defs');

    var gradient = definitions.append("linearGradient")
                .attr("id", "svgGradient")
                .attr("x1", "0%")
                .attr("x2", "100%")
                .attr("y1", "0%")
                .attr("y2", "0%");

    gradient.append('stop')
            .attr('class', 'start')
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", "red")
            .attr("stop-opacity", 1);            

    gradient.append("stop")
            .attr('class', 'end')
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "blue")
            .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    var barGroup = svg.append('g');
    var bars =  barGroup.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr("fill", "url(#svgGradient)")
            .attr('width', 30)
            .attr('height', barHeight - 10); 

    return(
        <div className="bargraph">  

        </div>
    ) 
}

export default Bargraph;
```

I would expect to get a horizontal bar chart inside a group  on order to apply transformation to the set of bars, then add the axis.

added comment:
My data comes as a prop to the component passed from a class component.

> Statistics.js

```
import  React from 'react';
import Bargraph from "../Bargraph/Bargraph.js";

class Statistics extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state= {
            data:[
               ["vocalist", "10"],
               ["producer", "15"],
               ["composers", "18"],
               ["engineers", "8"],
               ["instrumentalist", "15"],
               ["arrangers", "10"],
               ["artDirectors", "17"],
               ["albumNotes", "10"],
               ["narrators", "6"],
               ["musicDirectors", "12"]
            ],         
      }
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <Bargraph data={this.state.data}/>
      ) 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Where's your data? Check if your data is empty. Also, you should call third party libraries in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Hi @Raviteja : Just added comments to my question based on your coments.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tjibp5). Will add as an answer if it helps.